# Encoder Python Project

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

So I have created the text code for a school project. The purpose is to translate a string into a list of ASCII values and or vice versa. Now I am trying to add a user interface in order for it to be easier to use however nothing is working right now. I managed to create a user interface but none of the buttons work as I intended.

Here is the text-based code

```
from functools import partial


def program (str,my_fn):
    global i
    i=0
    while i<len(str):
        my_fn()
        i += 1

def encrypt(my_result,str,number=0):
    my_result.append(ord(str[i])-number)
def decrypt(my_result,str,number=0):
    my_result.append(chr(str[i]+number))
def password_generator():
    password = input("What would the password be:\n")
    numerical_password=[]
    program(password,partial(encrypt,numerical_password,password))
    global code
    code = sum(numerical_password)

#THE CODE FOR THE GUI STARTS HERE



#THE CODE FOR THE PROGRAM STARTS HERE
choice = ""
while choice != "Exit":
    choice = input("Do you want to Encrypt, Decrypt,  or Exit?\n")
    if choice == "Encrypt": #Encrypt
        option = input("Do you want a password?(Yes or No)\n")
        if option == "Yes":
            password_generator()
        else:
            code = 0

        answer = input("What would you like to encrypt:\n")
        message = []
        program(answer,partial(encrypt,message,answer,code))
        print (message)



    if choice == "Decrypt": #Decrypt
        option = input("Do you have a password?(Yes or No)\n")
        code= 0 
        if option == "Yes":
            password_generator()
        else:
            code = 0
        answer = [int(x) for x in input("(Please insert ONLY intergers seperated with commas)\nWhat would you like to decrypt:\n").split(",")]
        text =[]
        program(answer, partial(decrypt,text,answer,code))
        print("".join(text))
print("ThAnK yOu foR uSiNg eNcodER. HAve a nICe dAY!")
```

The issue in run into is some of the global variables will not be defined when I pressed the function for some reason.
Below is the code for buttons.

```
#Imports
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

#The Code for Setting up the GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("Note Taker")
root.geometry("250x250")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()


#Function for Program
def program (str,my_fn):
    global i
    i=0
    while i<len(str):
        my_fn()
        i += 1
def encrypt(my_result,str,number=0):
    my_result.append(ord(str[i])-number)
def decrypt(my_result,str,number=0):
    my_result.append(chr(str[i]+number))
def password_generator():
    password = input("What would the password be:\n")
    numerical_password=[]
    program(password,partial(encrypt,numerical_password,password))
    global code
    code = sum(numerical_password)


# #Functions of Buttons



def start():
    choice = input("Do you want to Encrypt, Decrypt,  or Exit?\n")
    if choice == "Encrypt": #Encrypt
        option = input("Do you want a password?(Yes or No)\n")
        if option == "Yes":
            password_generator()
        else:
            code = 0

        answer = input("What would you like to encrypt:\n")
        message = []
        program(answer,partial(encrypt,message,answer,code))
        print (message)



    if choice == "Decrypt": #Decrypt
        option = input("Do you have a password?(Yes or No)\n")
        code= 0 
        if option == "Yes":
            password_generator()
        else:
            code = 0
        answer = [int(x) for x in input("(Please insert ONLY intergers seperated with commas)\nWhat would you like to decrypt:\n").split(",")]
        text =[]
        program(answer, partial(decrypt,text,answer,code))
        print("".join(text))




#Buttons

Encrypt = Button(root, text="Start",command= start)
Encrypt.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

I just started programming so I know I am making several amaeture moves. However, I wish to keep my the functions since it is required for this project. Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it. Thanks

Comment: Why are using a the graphic interface `tkinter` to display the `Start` button then executing `start()` function with console interface `input()` and `print()` ?

Comment: The main reason is because I wish for the program to run in a loop.